# I am stuck on step 8 of Creating A USB boot Disk Mac Style

Tags: usb, mac

I coverted the file from ISO to dmg. I tried to step 8 I get this message.

```
dd: /Desktop/2ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.dmgof=/dev/rdisk1s1: No such file or directory
```

Over and over again. I try to retrace the the Ubuntu dmg file and I find it on my desktop. What is going on. I am running macbook 6 1 with mountain lion as the OS. I have a flash drive that is 4GB formarted to FAT32

Answer (score 0):

I tried **dragging my .dmg from Finder into Terminal** to get the exact path and avoid typos.

I suggest that there **needs to be a space** between the **dmg** and the **of**  shown in the following:

**.dmg of=/dev** (instead of  .dmgof=/dev shown above.)

And try typing **disk1** instead of disk1s1.

Best of luck,
Phil